# Double domain 301 rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, url-rewriting, debian

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.pl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test-test.pl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test-test.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.pl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I need help - I did something wrong and even though entering 'test.pl' moves you to 'www.test.pl', still the other domains stay as they did.

I want to make it like that: when you enter '(www.)test-test.pl' or '(www.)test-test.net' [all 4 adresses] you are moved to 'www.test.pl'.

I need it for my SEO, as my domain is falling down  - please help!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `OR`.

Without the `OR`, the rewrite engine will stop parsing at the first line. But that's simple to fix. 
This is how you probably want it to work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.pl$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test-test.pl$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test-test.net$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.pl/$1 [R=301,L]
```